# AsyncTask in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, viewdidload

I'm working with a async Task function in my viewDidLoad, by the returned response I'm changing the view (colors, text...), but I have "errors":

- sometimes when I change view and I come back to the view, I don't get my view background in orange, but I get it in Green (the green is returned after the response of the asynctask function) so it's not normal when I come back to the view it have to reload it...
- sometimes the view still in a orange background, but the function is already passed...

  ```
      super.viewDidLoad()

  self.lblUpdate.text = "Mise à jour des nouveaux paramètres en cours..."
  self.viewUpdate.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
  self.hideUpdateConstraint.isActive = false
  self.updateTopConstraint.isActive = true
  self.updateBottomConstraint.isActive = true

  if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {

      self.updateDown = true

      Reachability.checkUrl(urlString:Configuration.MyVariables.url, finished: { isSuccess in


          if isSuccess == true {

              ProcessingTasks.updateSimulationParams()
              self.lblUpdate.text = "Les nouveaux paramètres (taux, durée, montant...) ont été mis à jour."
              self.viewUpdate.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 151/255, green: 232/255, blue: 84/255, alpha: 1.0)
              print("ok c bon")

              self.updateDown = false


          } else {
              self.updateDown = true
              self.lblUpdate.text = "Les nouveaux paramètres (taux, durée, montant...) n'ont pas pu être mis à jour car notre service est actuellement indisponible."
              self.viewUpdate.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
          }
      })
  } else {
      updateDown = true
      self.lblUpdate.text = "Les nouveaux paramètres  (taux, durée, montant...) n'ont pas pu être mis à jour car vous ne disposez pas d'une connexion internet."
      self.viewUpdate.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  }

  self.hideUpdateConstraint.isActive = true
  self.updateTopConstraint.isActive = false
  self.updateBottomConstraint.isActive = false
  self.hideUpdateConstraint.constant = 20
  self.viewUpdate.isHidden = true


  view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SimulationViewController.handleTap(_:))))
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short suggestion. 
Try to override "viewDidAppear" function instead of "viewDidLoad". "viewDidAppear" should be triggered before view changes. "viewDidload" only triggered on views first load.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {      
    //Enter your code here       
}
```

Comment: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: I mean just call the function and change your UI as you need in viewDidAppear not in viewDidLoad. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, not bad, but here is a latence, the code run but it's take a time for having the changed view

Comment: It looks like you have some serious functions there. I use functions like  "Reachability.checkUrl" with timer. I think this function is responsible for your latency problem

Comment: How looks your function ?

Comment: My function checks the internet connection not a specific url. Its too long for this reply section.

Comment: Your problem is going to another issue now. Open another question for this and i will try to help.